# OpportunityLineItem formula field is not getting correct values in Test class

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, product

I have a formula field in OpportunityLineItem -'Is Available'(IsAvailable__c) which takes values from product object's checkbox field -'Is Available'

FORMULA : PricebookEntry.Product2.IsAvailable__c

When I tried to create dummy OpportunityLineItem record  within test class 'Is Available' formula field in OpportunityLineItem is returning me value as false,where as I am setting this value True at product level. Because of this major part of my class is not getting code coverage.
Can anyone please help me  to find what I am doing wrong here.

```
    static testmethod void TestMethod() {


    //Created A dummy Account and Opportunity records I.e  Acc & Opt

    //getting standard pricebook id
    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

    //Created a product
    Product2 prod = new Product2(
         Name = 'Product X',
         ProductCode = 'Pro-X',
         isActive = true,
         IsAvailable__c = True // setting field value as true
    );
    insert prod;


    //Created pricebook entry
    PricebookEntry pbEntry = new PricebookEntry(
         Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
         Product2Id = prod.Id,
         UnitPrice = 100.00,
         IsActive = true
    );
    insert pbEntry;

    //created opportunity line item.
    OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
         OpportunityId = opt.Id,
         units__c = 25,
         Type__c = 'No. Users',
         PricebookEntryId = pbEntry.Id,
         TotalPrice = 200,
         Quantity = 1
    );

    insert oli;

    system.debug('oli.IsAvailable__c ='+ oli.IsAvailable__c ); // This is returing me value as false

    Test.startTest(); 

    //calling my required methods here

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: After Inserting the Opportunity Line Item try to re- query and check the is-available Field.Formula field is calculated on the fly and the values will be available after record is committed to database

Comment: Thanks @VidhyasagaranMuralidharan ! That worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula fields are calculated at the time of query, so they will be calculated at runtime based on the currently saved values for that record. Generally there are two ways to achieve it:

1. Make a query to fetch formula field.
2. Use sobject class method "recalculateFormulas()" but it supports only non-cross object formula.

In your scenario, since formula field is cross object, you have to query it.

Comment: Thanks @Ayub ! That worked !

Comment: I'm glad I could help u :)